# Android:What is the difference between ImageView and View?

Tags: android, view, imageview, android-imageview

I know this is a very stupid question , but all I need with ImageView is to set a Image, A View can also setBackgroundDrawable,My question here is when should I use ImageView instead of  View . Thank you .

Comment: look at in dev site http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Answer (score 1):

View is the Super Class of ImageView. you can draw all android control event like as (Button, EditText,TextView, CheckBox) in view

ImageView you can draw an Image in imageView.

you can not directly add image on View but you can Typecast View to imageView.

you should add image on ImageView & ImageView will be added on Layout(View group)

Answer (score 0):

**Imageview** : Displays an arbitrary image, such as an icon. The ImageView class can load images from various sources (such as resources or content providers), takes care of computing its measurement from the image so that it can be used in any layout manager, and provides various display options such as scaling and tinting.

**View** : Provides classes that expose basic user interface classes that handle screen layout and interaction with the user.

Hope this helps.

For more details :

Image view : [Android ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)

View : [Android View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your View should display an image, use ImageView. As the name suggests, it is designed for displaying images (whereas View is a more generic class), so it contains a lot of useful methods for that specific purpose, such as setting the image's alpha, color filter, or scale type (to specify how the image should be resized to fit the View), which are not available to the View widget.

See the docs for more details : [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)